# how to use .after() on elements that are not in DOM when the page loaded. (injected after page loaded)

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am having a small issue with jQUery.

I am working on a script which injects some html code after a div which is not there when the page is load , that means after the page loaded , a script will inject that div into the html.

i am using the jquery code below to inject html after that div(injecteddiv)

```
$('#firstdiv').after('<div id="injecteddiv"></div>');

$('#injecteddiv').after('<p>hello</p>');
```

it wont work ,nothing is injected after that div(#injecteddiv), i think its the "div injected after page load" issue.
is there any way around it? Thnaks.

P/S I have jquery library installed.

Comment: Why don't you just call it again in the same routine that injects the content into the div?

Comment: hey what is the error? since we tried the code at our end it add the `<p>` after `injecteddiv`

Answer (score 1):

The `#` is only used when you specidy an id in a selector, it's not part of the id.

```
$('#firstdiv').after('<div id="injecteddiv"></div>');
```

Comment: @sm21guy: With that change the code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/udTe9/

Comment: hm , wait let me double check everything , actually in my test , the script is a toolbar and it is injected after the page load, i want to inject something after that toolbar. so im using the example above.